# ld: file was built for unsupported file format on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos

I have to build a project with shared objects compiled on a other x64_86 computer. I have this error:

```
cc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -I./include src/server.c
obj/tftp.o -o bin/server -L./lib64 -lSocketUDP -lAdresseInternet -lpthread
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file ./lib64/libSocketUDP.so, file was
built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture
being linked (x86_64): ./lib64/libSocketUDP.soignoring file
./lib64/libAdresseInternet.so, file was built for unsupported file format (
0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):
./lib64/libAdresseInternet.so
```

The architecture of my Mac is x86_64 and shared objects were compiled on a x86_64. The compilation works on my Linux computer.

Here my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -I./include
LDLIBS = -L./lib64
LDFLAGS = -lSocketUDP -lAdresseInternet -lpthread

all: obj/tftp.o bin/server bin/client

obj/tftp.o: src/tftp.c
    mkdir -p obj
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

bin/server: src/server.c obj/tftp.o
    mkdir -p bin
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

bin/client: src/client.c obj/tftp.o
    mkdir -p bin
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) -r obj

distclean:
    $(RM) -r obj bin
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do that as this "other x86_64 computer" was clearly running Linux and generating [ELF-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object files.

```
0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46
0x7F 'E'  'L'  'F'
```

OSX/iOS uses [Mach-O format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) object files and cannot be linked against different types of object file.

You will need to compile all the code under OSX.

Answer (score 4):

Your SocketUDP lib is probably built for Linux. Linux and OS X use different and incompatible object files, ELF vs . Mach-O.

You have to build the library on OS X as well.

Comment: Is there any way to compile the library for both plateforms?

Comment: @mathieu_b You can cross-compile to a foreign target to build macos dynamic libraries from your Linux box.  You cannot produce a single file that works for both platforms though, if that's what you are wondering.

Comment: @casey Alright, I don't have the library sources, my teacher compiled it. I need to found another solution, thank you!

Comment: @mathieu_b You could install VirtualBox on your Mac and then install a Linux distribution on there and run.

Comment: @casey there are technically fat binaries as a workaround for cross platform binaries