# Failed to do 'make' on .c and .s files using Mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to compile a simple project with .c and .s files using my Mac.
When I run 'make' it goes threw on the compilation, and I think it failed when its trying to link (not sure).

Here is the error it shows:

```
gcc -m32 -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -m32 -g -Wall -c -o numbers.o numbers.c
nasm -g -f macho -w+all -o add.o add.s
gcc -m32 -g -Wall -o run main.o numbers.o add.o
ld: malformed file
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
platform:        zippered
                 ^~~~~~~~
 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

and I'll add the makefile as well:

```
run: main.o numbers.o add.o
    gcc -m32 -g -Wall -o run main.o numbers.o add.o
main.o: main.c
    gcc -m32 -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
numbers.o: numbers.c
    gcc -m32 -g -Wall -c -o numbers.o numbers.c
add.o: add.s
    nasm -g -f macho -w+all -o add.o add.s
.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    rm -f *.o run
```

Comment: MacOS uses macho, not elf, object files.  It does use the same user-space function calling convention as Linux, though, so if you aren't making any `int 0x80` or `syscall` system calls from hand-written asm, you can probably just change to `-f macho`.  It does decorate asm symbols with a leading `_` where ELF/Linux doesn't.

Comment: hmm it doesn't look like it made any difference :/

Comment: Did you `make clean` after changing the Makefile?  Your `.o` has no make dependency on the Makefile itself...  If you did, then update your question with the exact error message you're getting now.  If it still includes `unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 ...` then your system is insane; those ASCII codes literally spell ELF as part of the magic number that identifies an ELF file.

Comment: your'e right, it changed,I updated the question

Comment: You haven't yet.  Next time edit first *then* reply; SO lights up the notification button right away.

Comment: [Compile assembler in nasm on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14997777) says `nasm -f macho` (aka `macho32`) should make the right kind of object files.  IDK if you have something in your `.asm` that makes it fail, or if modern MacOS doesn't work the same way?  Or if using raw `ld` instead of `gcc` (actually clang) would help.  It might also be a good idea to remove the ELF output and just show the macho to avoid making readers look through that already-solved problem which is a duplicate of [ld: file was built for unsupported file format on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36694088)

Comment: I'm pretty new with c and assembly, not really sure what to do with what your'e saying.

Comment: I'm just saying to edit your question as if you were posting it new, just about the current error message and Makefile.  If any future readers have that `-f elf` problem, they can already find the answer if they search on that error message, so that part is uninteresting and doesn't need to exist on SO as part of *this* question.  I don't know why you're getting your current error message; I don't have a Mac.  It would be a good idea to post a tiny [mcve] of the .c and .asm files, preferably just something like this for the asm: `global _add` / `_add:` /  `lea  eax, [rdi + rsi]` / `ret`

Comment: Which macOS version have you been programming for?  Note that support for 32 bit code has been removed from the most recent version.  This could be the issue you observe.

Comment: Yeah @fuz its probably the reason, I gave up and using VM with ubuntu instaed.
Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do we have a canonical duplicate for “no 32 bit code on macOS” yet?  I've tried to find one but wasn't successful.

Comment: @fuz: not that I know of.  Maybe some Q&As that could be a duplicate, but not one that sticks out in my mind as being canonical.

Comment: @YoavKeissar: Are you following some tutorial?  If not, might as well just use 64-bit code instead; 32-bit code is already obsolete for your main platform (MacOS), and basically obsolete elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah I understand what you're saying, but I'm obligated by my university, so I don't have the the option to choose..

Comment: @YoavKeissar: I was surprised you switched from MacOS to Linux; and if you could do that I thought maybe you could switch to 64-bit MacOS more easily.  Apparently that's not the case, but no harm in pointing it out.  (Linux and MacOS use the same function-calling convention, but different calling conventions for 32-bit system calls (or for 64-bit syscalls same convention but different call numbers).  Only MacOS uses a leading `_` in asm symbol names for C name, like `_printf`. )  That's why I was surprised you could switch OSes easily.